# Where is this on topic

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621570/memorychip-building-adress-decoder

Simply wondering, it is about computer science in the broad sense. Decoders are the basic components that build assembler - so to understand any language implementation you have to understand the basics and hence how chips work.

Why is it off-topic, and on which Stack Exchange site would it be on-topic and have a chance to be answered?

Comment: It is not needed at all for understanding assembler, or programming. It is as much about hardware as it can go.

Comment: yes, but to understand assembler you need to understand hardware - assembler is a direct translation of said hardware. But besides that - why is this offtopic, and why can't hardware questions (that actually tackle how hardware work, not what is best hardware) be ontopic?

Comment: No, you do not need to know how many 2 bit address decoders are needed. This has no direct impact on the use of assembler.

Comment: To further stress it: questions about how the graphical card communicates with the CPU/motherboard should be asked somewhere. I think they might fit very well into stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question belongs to [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com). It is about electrical engineering, and only passingly relates to programming, as address decoders have many uses in digital electronics beyond that which is programmable. More so, there it would then probably be closed as a duplicate of existing question.

Comment: Ok now that is a solution..

Comment: If you ask there, I'd answer in an instant

Comment: Well I thought electronics.stackexchange was only for things like emplifiers, and wave modulation. I remember actually wondering where to ask... Still shouldn't this be opted to move instead of close then? (It's now outdated though, I've found the answer after a few days of personal search while I knew the answer should've been easy).

Comment: @paul23, there is no migration path from SO to Electronics (only to Meta, SU, TeX, DBA and SharePoint)

Comment: Hmm that would bmake actually a suggestion for a new feature - automatic move paths. As stackexchange family grows it becomes more and more difficult to "know" all places and "know" the best location.

Comment: Then write a good feature request...

Comment: There are no answers to move; just delete it and re-ask it, @paul23. No need to make things complicated.